# Assembly - shr instruction turn on carry flag?

Tags: assembly, x86

I saw the next code:

```
shr AL, 1
   jnc bit_0
```

I don't understand when the carry flag is turn on due to shr instrucrion?

Thanks

Comment: It's testing whether AL is even or odd.

Answer (score 11):

`shr AL, 1` moves all of the bits in `AL` right one place.

The original rightmost bit is shifted out of the `AL` register into the carry flag (and the new leftmost bit is set to 0).  For example:

```
 +------------------------+               +------------------------+
 | 1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1 |               | 0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0 |
 +------------------------+               +------------------------+
    \  \  \  \  \  \  \  \       or          \  \  \  \  \  \  \  \
     \  \  \  \  \  \  \  \                   \  \  \  \  \  \  \  \
 +------------------------+ CF            +------------------------+ CF
 |(0) 1  0  0  1  0  1  0 | 1             |(0) 0  1  1  0  0  1  0 | 0
 +------------------------+               +------------------------+
```

---

In your comment on another answer:

> My book gives the next example: Before shift: AL = 10101110 ; shr AL, 1 ; After shift: 01011100, CF = 1 ; Is it mistake?

If that's what it says, then yes.  That's a left shift (`shl AL, 1`), not a right shift: the bits in `AL` have all been moved left by one place, and the carry flag has been set to the bit that was shifted out of the left-hand end.

Answer (score 0):

to add some clarifications :

shr AL, 1 ; it will (SH)ift (R)ight (1)x the value contained in AL register, which is 8 lower bits of AX register. Hence it will divide the value contained in AL by 2.

If AL was previously even like 0b100 (4) it will become 0b10 (2) and put 0 in the carry flag.
Carry Flag is bit 0 in the flag register https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register

If AL was previously an odd value like 0b101 (5) then it will become 0b10 (2) and put 1 in the flag register. Hence the carry flag will act like a remainder if you divide by 2.

jnc bit_0 ; It will (J)ump to label 'bit_0' if (N)o (C)arry flag was set, i.e if the value was even (like 0b100 in the above example) before the shift.